# can't convert UIColor Hexadecimal string value to Hash value

Tags: hash, hex, uicolor

IN my project i want to convert UIcolour Hexadecimal string value to hash value..

when i perform NSLOG function to print value of color .i get a value like **"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.866667 0.886275 0.415686 1 "**. i want to convert it to hash value . Thanks in advance

i am using this function to convert a hexadecimal integer value to hash value

//For getting UIColor from Hex value

```
- (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
unsigned rgbValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
[scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
[scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];

return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)hexStringWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    if ([color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X",
                                          round(255 * red),
                                          round(255 * green),
                                          round(255 * blue)];
    }
    // Could not get RGB values for color
    return nil;
}
```